# hide css class without js on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a html menu:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="active">Item one</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item two</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item three</a></li>
</ul>
```

and css:

```
ul li a{
     color: black;
}
ul li a:hover, ul li a.active{ /* it was ul li a:hover for two times */
     color: red;
}
```

When I'm hovering on a non-active element, there is two red elements and it is normal.
The problem is changing color for hover-element only and removing it on active (turn to black).
Is there any trick to do this without JS?

**edited: there was an error. ctrl-c -> ctrl-v is evil**

Comment: Your CSS looks wrong. Is that supposed to be `ul li a.active, ul li a:hover` rather than `ul li a:hover, ul li a:hover`?

Comment: ul li a:active {color: black; }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your ul element isn't bigger than the space your li s take up:

```
ul:hover a.active
{
    color: black;
}
```

Or possibly Shawn's answer, depending on if you're talking about the class active or the link status.

Comment: you are welcome Alexander, but you might want to check this answer as accepted one, just so that other members could know that this issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul li a:active {
     color: black;
}
```